# Cordova not accessing external urls

Tags: cordova, cors, ionic-framework

I am trying to access this resources from my Cordova app:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

If i add this line my app is crashing.

```
<img src="http://192.168.1.2:8084/mobapp/api/v1.0/common/viewphoto/d4170230-6086-11e5-a98d-7bdc2a9aa3c7/0d760d00-6087-11e5-a98d-7bdc2a9aa3c7/photo_tumb" width="200px" height="200px"/>
```

Here is am getting `ERR_TIME_OUT` error

```
<img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2015/googles-17th-birthday-6231962352091136-hp.png" width="200px" height="200px"/>
```

Here is am getting `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error.

i have added `<access origin="*"/>` in config.xml.
i have added `cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.1.0 "Whitelist"` plugin

Comment: You need to add the *Content Security Policy*. It is relatively new and at [the bottom of cutting edge documentation pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

Comment: After spending hours i found that problem was with my mobile network

Comment: Can you give use some more details for any developers reading this later? What network? What was the actual cause? TIA Jesse

Comment: The issue was with my mobile hardware. It was frequently connecting disconnecting to internet but always showing wifi signal. and that i never guessed that it may be the reason. When i browse some pages i found that there is no internet access

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the *Content Security Policy*. It is relatively new and at [the bottom of cutting edge documentation pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

Example:

`<!-- Allow requests to foo.com -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' foo.com">`

More details here in #10
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)